# Doing math in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, math

The following is a snippet from a script that Generates random passwords with a length of the users choice. I have got the script functioning perfectly as a GUI.

I would like to add some extra functionality, at the bottom of the script is some info for the user

`The passwords generated by this application are very strong, here is an example of the strength you can achieve by using this application;`

```
Length of Password:
$newnumber

Character Combinations:
${#matrix}

Calculations Per Second: 
4 billion

Possible Combinations:   2 vigintillion
```

`Based on an average Desktop PC making about 4 Billion calculations per second it would take about
    21 quattuordecillion years to crack your password.`

```
As a number that's 21,454,815,022,336,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years!"
```

How would I get bash to calculate the answer of

```
`21 quattuordecillion years`
```

from

```
Length of Password:
$newnumber

Character Combinations:
${#matrix}

Calculations Per Second: 
4 billion

Possible Combinations:   2 vigintillion
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022 is your friend. (Granted, you're only dealing with integers here, but they're integers larger than native datatypes will store).

Comment: BTW, this question is considerably more broad than it needs to be. (You can ask how to do large-integer math without needing to give us the entirety of your problem description and text!)

Comment: I like to be thorough in my question that way i dont get questions as answers. I couldnt break it down much more, it says what i have and what i want. dont forget im fairly new to bash, and rubbish at math.

Comment: "Questions as answers" are actively disallowed here -- they're flaggable, after which the mods will delete them. (Questions as comments, of course, are a different thing). Anyhow -- questions that require but don't include MVCEs (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- **minimal,** complete, verifiable examples -- aren't allowed either, in the sense that there's a close reason associated with them, so if the community decides to vote-to-close, that provides cause. Your example here is anything but minimal.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do math from bash is to use the bc commandline calculator.
Here is how you can call it from a bash script:

```
answer=$(bc << LIMIT_STRING
your math operations here
LIMIT_STRING
)
```

Comment: hey thanks bc is nice and simple to use I have progressed a little with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way that provides an intuitive and flexible approach to math in bash is the package [[**calc**]](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/calc-download.html). I have worked with and contributed to calc for a number of years. It is a fully capable (scientific) command line floating point math application. Use in bash is as simple as:

```
ans=$( calc -p "sqrt($a^2 + $b^2 + $c^2)" )
```

It is definitely worth a look if you find `bc` a bit awkward to use.

Comment: thanks @David, `calc` seems like a possible way forward. I am still having problems actually committing the sum in the correct format to aquire the answer I would like. Maybe you could help? I wanted something like **[[this website](https://howsecureismypassword.net/)]** in my final program any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a pretty scary site... What issue are you having obtaining a `sum` and how does that relate to the link? You will have to look at the number limitation in BASH (I don't know offhand). I suspect, that you will have to reduce the number to an exponential form and then use the exponential to come up with 'quattuordecillion' in some sort of lookup table based on the value of the exponent.